# php breaking up a number variable?

Tags: php, string, explode

Is there a way to break up the value in an assigned variable without any blank spaces?

eg.

```
$var = 123456789;
```

i could do this with an explode array buy because there are no spaces im having difficulty.

```
$result = explode("", $var);

$results[0] = $a;
$result[1] = $b;
$result[2] = $c;
```

etc...

```
$a would = 1
$b would = 2
$c would = 3
```

etc...

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that best fits your question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [`str_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) is for. It  will implicitly convert it's argument to a string:

```
$num = 12345;

$arr1 = str_split($num);

print_r($arr1);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php). You can now split a string into individual characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

```
$var = 123456789;
$result = str_split($var);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = 123456789;
$length = strlen($var);

for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++)  {
echo substr($var, $i, 1);
}
```

//echos each number

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
function mySplit($in){
    $ret = array();
    $in = strval($in);
    $count = strlen($in);
    for($i =  0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $ret[] = substr($in,$i,1);
    }
    return $ret;
}
var_dump(explodeNumber(123));
echo "<br />";
var_dump(str_split(123));
```

array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" }

array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" }